# Why does a line of code that is outside a function (when the function is called in another file) prints out?

Tags: python, function

When I create a function in a file (let's call it `demostration_1.py`) and some other line of code outside the function, as shown below:

```
def adult(x):
    return x >= 18

print('hello world')
```

and then I call this function in another file (let's call it `demostration_2.py`)

```
from demostration_1 import adult

print(adult(18))
```

it prints out

```
hello world
True
```

So, Why does it print `hello world` if I'm only calling for the `adult()` function?

Comment: when you use the `from <module>` syntax it actually imports the entire module, and runs all the code within it. otherwise, it wouldn't know what the function definition of an import actually is (hope that makes sense)

Comment: This is one reason why we use the `if __name__=='__main__':` idiom: so we can sections that run when the file is run by itself, but not when it is imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to expand on my comment above, but imagine that your module `a` contains the following code:

```py
def adult(x):
    return x >= MIN_YEARS


MIN_YEARS = 18
```

This *works* perfectly fine, but only because the entire module is loaded when you call `import a` or `from a import adult`.

But if you *didn't want* a block of code to be run whenever a module was imported, you can hide that logic away within an `if __name__=='__main__:'` block at the end of the file, as @Tim Roberts also mentioned. So with the below approach, you won't see `hello world` printed whenever this module is imported by another one.

```py
def adult(x):
    return x >= 18


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('hello world')
```

Comment: Ok, thanks I understood, but now if I only want to print the code that is within ```if __name__ == '__main__':``` in another file, how can I do it?

Comment: Well, I guess simplest way will be to move that code to a function `foo` and call it from another file